# Combat spambots by hiding email address (display: none)

Tags: jquery, spam-prevention, email-spam

Is it possible to prevent spambots from crawling all over my email address if I set it `display: none`? I had an idea for a little minigame if you will, where the user clicks the link for the email and it then displays one or two "are you sure you're not a bot" sort of questions. Once these have been answered, it then displayed the real link.

The issue is I'm assuming that bots can see the link because it's obviously there in the HTML even if it's not visible. Is there a way around this?

Also, I would want these questions to fade in, but as I understand it the CSS3 transitions don't support the display or visibility properties. Would I have to resort to jQuery? If so, could anyone direct me to alternative to fading in elements when switching from `display: none` to `display: block`?

Comment: The best way to hide your email address is in server-side code, and have users fill out a form instead. Of course, the smarter spambots can fill out comment forms as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, `display: none` would not work.

The only real way around this is to not have it in your HTML whatsoever. Make it an image for example, or use JavaScript to descramble it into individual elements that can be placed absolutely (and individually) for a browser's human viewer to see correctly.

Note that if you go the image route, spambots can of course read images, so perhaps you should obfuscate it a little bit with some random images like the good old captchas.

With regards to CSS3 not supporting `visibility`/`display`, you'd be right, but you can use the opacity property to fade in the content of however you decide to display your email address. `opacity` is fully supported by CSS3 transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Most crawlers analyse the markup of a page, not the visual rendered version. Using `display: none` will have very little effect.

Also, you don't need to use jQuery for fading effects. Setting the opacity and then using the following will work nicely:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
```

Comment: I'm aware of opacity transitions, but this scenario assumed that the element would not actually be in the document as opposed to just being invisible.

Comment: You do know that when an element has the CSS property of `display: none` it is still in the document, don't you?

Comment: @Bobe `display:none` does not remove the element from the document, only the visual. (Oops @BenM beat me too it +1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing the e-mail address, you may want to implement a contact form. You can protect that form with a captcha or some honeypot approach. Also, you may render the form using Javascript, since many bots won't run Javascript (I hope).

Comment: Yeah I know I could use a form, but I want to experiment with other methods.

Comment: You could obfuscate the e-mail address in javascript as well. If you add it using Javascript, or even as the result of an AJAX request, it will be harder for bots to just get the e-mail address.